# Reusing elements and DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have two classes, which reference the third:

```
class Data1
{
   public Named Xxx { get; set; }
   public SomeClass1 Foo { get; set; }
   ...
}

class Data2
{
   public Named Yyy { get; set; }
   public SomeClass2 Bar { get; set; }
   ...
}

class Named
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Now, I would like to display both `Data1` & `Data2`:

```
<TreeView DataContext={Binding Path=Data1}>
  <TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <ContentControl xml:space="preserve">Name: </ContentControl>
          <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Xxx.Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </TreeViewItem.Header>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem><!-- somehow display Foo --></TreeViewItem>
    <!-- More TreeViewItems, specific to Data1 -->
  </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>

<TreeView DataContext={Binding Path=Data2}>
  <TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <ContentControl xml:space="preserve">Name: </ContentControl>
          <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Yyy.Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </TreeViewItem.Header>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem><!-- somehow display Bar --></TreeViewItem>
    <!-- More TreeViewItems, specific to Data2 -->
  </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>
```

So, markup is different, except for `TreeViewItem` that displays `Named` class. I would like to reuse markup for this `TreeViewItem`. It is too simple to make `UserControl` of it, but it is still a little more complicated than shown in example. So, I would really like to do something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <TreeViewItem x:Key="Named">
    <TreeViewItem.Header>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl xml:space="preserve">Name: </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem.Header>
  </TreeViewItem>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then just use it like this:

```
<TreeView DataContext={Binding Path=Data1}>
  <TreeView.Items>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Named" />
  </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>
```

As you can see, `Data1`'s property name for `Named` is `Xxx`, while `Data2`'s property name for `Named` is `Yyy`. So, I have to pass that somehow to my resource. But how?

E.g. how do I set the `DataContext` of this `StaticResource` subtree to `Xxx` for `Data1`?

Something like this doesn't work:

```
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Named" DataContext={Binding Path=Xxx} />
```

Sorry for the long question.

**Edit**:

All I want is a piece of XAML, capable of displaying a `Named` instance. So, I want to be able to specify where to get the instance (from `Xxx` or `Yyy`) **outside** of this piece, so I can reuse it.

**Edit2**: here is the solution with `ControlTemplate`, however it doesn't work well: the `TreeViewItem` becomes unselectable. What's wrong?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Named" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
    </TreeViewItem>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- now use the template: -->
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem Template="{StaticResource Named}" 
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=Xxx}" />
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I took a nap today and when I woke up, I suddenly realized what the answer is! Here it is:

```
<!-- In resources: -->
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="Named">
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- now use the template: -->
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource Named}" 
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=Xxx}" />
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look into the whole templating topic.
Instead of manually creating instances of `TreeViewItem` you should bind you list of items to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property and then specify an `TreeView.ItemTemplate` which is your reusable static resource.
If you have mixed data types then you can use `TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector` to dynamically select a `DataTemplate` you desire

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx for more information

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I am aware of `ItemsSource`, however in this case, as you can see, there is no collection to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, torvin, you should use DataTemplate. Not only ItemsControl supports templating, ContentControl also have this feature. There is ContentTemplate property. ContentControl also hooks template automatically by using DataTemplate.DataType property.

So, you can create DataTemplate that represents Named object:

```
<...Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Named}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</...Resources>
```

Then you should set Named object as a Content:

```
<TreeViewItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl xml:space="preserve">Name: </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Xxx}" />
    </StackPanel>
</TreeViewItem.Header>
```

That's all! I hope I understand you correctly this time :)

Comment: Ugh.. Come on! Too much code! At this point, it would be simpler to just write a UserControl...

Comment: Even if you have a UserControl, it cannot help you to avoid Xxx or Yyy specification. My solution isn't perfect too, because it doesn't allow WPF to track changes of the Name property. But converter can be modified to achieve this. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank, Marat, but it looks like you misunderstood me. I have two completely different `TreeView`s, they aren't bound to the same source. So I don't need to avoid Xxx or Yyy specification. I just want to avoid this specification in the common markup. In another words, I just want a piece of XAML to display `Named` class, with no knowledge of where does the instance of `Named` come inside this piece. I should add this to the question...

Comment: Thanks again. That is something I try to achieve, but I want the whole `TreeViewItem` (I need to customize both it's Header and subitems), not just `ContentControl`. And if I do that, `TreeViewItem` becomes unselectable somehow...

Comment: It's a wrong way. You'll have more problems in future. For example, TreeViewItem cannot lie in two different visual trees at the same time. You should go with Martin's answer.

Comment: It can, if you use `ControlTemplate`. I'll update my question now to show you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Binding`s in a `StaticResource`, use the [Hillberg's freezable trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/21/model-see_2c00_-model-do.aspx)